# How can I format text with borders and get it printed?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry for my title, I can't think of a good one.
Anyway. Can someone help me give an idea how to achieve a format like this? what to use? (ex: richtextbox) how to create the cell borders? and it should also be printable.

[image: pay slip]

Comment: What is the shape of your text? Where is it from? Database?

Comment: Yes all that should be put there will come from the database. What do you mean text shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you heard about [iTextSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/iTextSharpTutorial.aspx)? You can create tables with itextsharp. But you need to save it as pdf format. So the idea here is create a table format like that and save it as pdf then open it to a webrowser or some kind of a pdf renderer by then you will be able to print it as well.

**Here's a simple code for creating table:**

```
    private bool Test(string pdf_file) 
    {
        bool ret = false;
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        try
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdf_file, FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();

            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Header Column"));
            cell.Colspan = 3;
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; 
            table.AddCell(cell);
            table.AddCell("row1:col1");
            table.AddCell("row1:col2");
            table.AddCell("row1:col3");
            doc.Add(table);

            ret = true;
        }
        catch (DocumentException de)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(de.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ioe.Message);
        }

        doc.Close();

        if(ret)
            MessageBox.Show("File has been created");

        return ret;
    }
```

**PDF Output:**
[image]

Comment: I have no idea why you'd suggest that.

Comment: the OP can create that kind of format using itextsharp. is it not a good idea to use itextsharp?

Comment: Maybe you should give a simple example. It's possible I'm simply misunderstanding what iTextSharp is good for.

Comment: see my edit. the PDF output image is the pdf file that has been created.

Comment: Is this the best way for achieving that kind of format, using ItextSharp? Can I use it for printable documents? Thanks!

Comment: There are still other ways of achieving that kind format. This one is just a suggestion. I'm not sure if you can use it as printable doc formats. I think there's no feature for that yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use a [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)? Seems a lot easier then trying to maintain consistent column widths.

Comment: is it possible to generate numerous format like that in a datagridview?

Comment: it's designed to be used for displaying database records. Not sure if you could easily match your exact format to it. though you could probably change your format to make it work pretty easy

Comment: No printing support.  Hard to avoid recommending Excel here, it was made for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Create Local Report (.rdlc) in Report Viewer to do that.
Using This the user can extract your data in different format(Excel,PDF and CSV).

[Dynamic Report](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Microsoft_Dynamic_Reports.aspx)

[Using Winform Reports](http://64.4.11.252/en-us/library/aa337089%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Regards